# SpringDataMongoDB - Cannot find Persistent Entity for type class when using multiple MongoDB Connectors

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I am creating rest API which is connecting to 2 MongoDB Database server. I have to disable to `Springboot AutoConfiguration` and create config class to access both the DB server.

The rest API will connect to same entity. I have created 2 entities (in different packages), 2 repository (in different packages) and configured my Mongo template to look for that repository.

When I am calling the Spring Data Rest URL to get the entity, it gives me:

> "ERROR o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler - Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class" error.

It is working fine when I am calling the method using controller.

I have tried using converter like below but that too didnt work.

```
MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(
    new DefaultDbRefResolver(dfm1ReplicaFactory(this.mongoProperties.getDfm1Replica())),
    new MongoMappingContext());
    converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
    converter.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: Thinking outside the box: what exactly is the reason to connect to two database servers?

Comment: Well the design structure is such that one the mongo Db is the replica of application database which holds real time data and another one holds the archived/older data. All the 3 db has same schema and tables. My requirement is to connect to the replica db and the archived ones to check for different set of data in one of the table.

Comment: The api is working fine when I call the repository method using  controller. But when I call the repository method it gives me that Persistent Entity error. I believe the error is due to configuring 2 database instance because when I use only one db config and let spring do the auto configuration, I dont get that error.